# jQuery mouseenter() and mouseleave() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have two simple script html:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
.myBtn{
    display: none
}
.myBtnReg{
    display: block
}
</style>
<button class="myBtnReg" id="btn1" >Click Me!</button>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("button").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).attr("class", "myBtn");
    });
    $("button").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).attr("class", "myBtnReg");
    });
});
```

I'm trying to make an effect where the button changes class when ever  the mouse enters and change it back when the mouse leaves, the code above doesn't seem to work properly, when I put my mouse over the button it flickers, so I assume I changes class constantly for some reason.

Comment: It's because you're changing the display property, when the button disappears, the mouseleave fires, then it reappears, and the mouseenter fires, making it dissapear etc. and you get "flicker"

Comment: Good lesson to learn...

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of that

Comment: @adeneo Please put your answer below so that it can be accepted and the post is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `button` inside `div` and then toggleClass of `button` when you hover over `div` (you also need to set fixed **height** on div)

```js
$('div').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('button').toggleClass('myBtn');
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
}
.myBtn {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="myBtnReg" id="btn1">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using a `div` it might be better to use `visibility`  instead of `display` in the this case, because then you don't need to used a fixed height.

Comment: I agree but OP wants to change the `display` so i think this is more appropriate answer.

Comment: But with a `div` container the result is the same as with `visibility` except that you have to set a fixed height, and that there is an even larger active range in width, because `div` has display `block` and `button` is `inline-block`.

Comment: Actually it's not the same, because with `display: none` you remove element from elements flow and with `visibility` you don't as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/591/ and https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/592/

Comment: But then your example is also not the same as the one of the OP. If you add `Lorem ipsum dolor.` to the example of the OP, then a mouseover at `Lorem ipsum dolor.` would not trigger a change of the display. What if you want add more content below the button, would you always place it inside of the `div`? Then a mouseover below the button will always trigger the change of the display. If you add it outside then of the `div` then you have the same effect as if you use `visibility` because you have set a `height` to the `div`. If `display` or `visibility`  is better depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

your style should be like

```
.myBtn{
    background-color:RED;
}
.myBtnReg{
    background-color:Green;
}
```

your total html is like this

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
  .myBtn{
        background-color:RED;
    }
    .myBtnReg{
        background-color:Green;
    }
</style>
<button class="myBtnReg" id="btn1" >Click Me!</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP does not want to change the color, but to show and hide the `button`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question as asked by the original poster (OP). I recommend editing your answer  to provide a good answer to the OP's question.